# Group policy not pushed to client for offline files setting

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I have setup group policy for "Offline Files" but I noticed that the configuration is not pushed to clients. With another setup I had no problem.

The configuration path is `\\Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\Offline Files\Allow` or `Disallow` use of the Offline Files feature

The server runs Windows 2012 and clients mostly Windows 7. Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: what does `gpresult /h %userprofile%\test.html` say?

Comment: I already generating the result using same command as you mention and not found the setting affected to client. I also already generate it in domain server and it show the result.

Comment: I also already manually update the gpo using gpupdate /force both in client and server. But the result still same, I need this configuration because the offline file often cause problem accessing file server when network error.

Comment: did you follow those instructions? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649078.aspx

Comment: Where is the GPO linked? Are you filtering the GPO (Security or WMI)? Have you rebooted any of the client machines?

Comment: sorry for late reply SimonS, i am not following that link instruction as i want only to disable offline file. is my step to only configure "\\Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\Offline Files\Allow or Disallow use of the Offline Files feature" wrong to disable offline file on client? should I follow all instruction on your link?

Comment: hi joeqwerty, no I am not filtering the GPO. I linked the GPO to default domain and security setting to default (authenticated users) and I also already tried rebooting the client machines.